# How to GET specific data from an API

Tags: python, request

Hello I want to get forecastings for London for 3 days from https://www.metaweather.com/api/ using python but when I use this url: 'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/2013/4/27/' I get jason with forecasts for different times of this day. I want one forecasting for this day.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
import requests
r=requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/2013/4/27/').text
weather=json.loads(r)
```